# AngularJS ngRoute #! error (possibly an nginx error)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nginx

I'm using an Angular version of 1.5.9 with the ngRoute module. Everything in my project is wrapped up in a Grunt task. When I use my grunt watch function, while developing, everything works fine, alls the redirects are functioning properly.
But after my production code has been pushed to gitlab and been build with uglifyjs, etc and the code has been deployed to my staging server all routes fail. Requesting `https://example.com/` redirects me to `https://example.com/#!/` instead of `https://example.com/#/`

Building the code locally and spinning up a python webserver does not result into this error.

Currently I'm using nginx as a webserver with basic TLS Settings enabled, but mostly stock configuration on Ubuntu Xenial.

In an other project, build from the same template, using the same build process, the same production server, and using the same configuration with nginx (just another vhost) don't result into this error.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't think this a duplicate considering OP says it works on a different server. OP didn't even state what version of angular is in use. @georgeawg

Comment: Actually the suggested duplicate did fix my error. This thread just didn't appear during my research